# JSF 1.2 - values are not retained after page reload

Tags: jsf-1.2

Problem - I am a beginer with JSF 1.2. I have an input text box and a command button.
After typing some in the text box and pressing the command button, the page is getting reloaded but the value does not get retained in text box.

**web.xml**

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>myBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>MyBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

**View code :**

```
<h:inputText binding="#{myBean.inputComponent}" value="#{myBean.inputValue}" />
<h:commandButton value="submit" action="#{myBean.action}" />
```

Comment: View and Bean code will be interresting to help you...

Comment: OK. Is there any specific API to help me in JSF 1.2 ?

Comment: Actually I was asking to see your code, how do you think we can help without it?

Comment: Are you sending a redirect after submit or so?

Comment: What is `#{myBean.action}` (bean code), are you using `#{myBean.inputValue}` inside another view? If yes, this is a scope problem, in JSF 1.X you don't have `ViewScoped` so you can use `SessionScope` or use `a4j:keepAlive` see [here](http://mshawally.blogspot.ca/2012/06/view-scope-in-jsf-12-using-richfaces.html).

Comment: The Bean Code is very simple. I am just trying to get the inputText value using a getter. And I am not using any nested views. Only one <f:view/>. And can I use any state saving mechanism if it is worth ? Thanks.

Comment: @BalusC No I am not sending a re-direct after submit. Thanks.